# State.go in service angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Can I use `$state.go()` inside a service in AngularJS? 
 I am trying to inject `$state` inside a factory service and trying to change the state. Is this possible?

**Config:**

```
.state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        templateUrl: "templates/app.html",
        controller: 'AppController',
        resolve: {
            auth: ['RouteProtectService', function(RouteProtectService) {
                RouteProtectService.checkVerifiedUser();
            }]
        }
    })
```

**Service:**

```
.factory('RouteProtectService', ['$state',
    function($state) {
        function userVerifiedCheck() {
            $state.go('app.preference');
        }

        return {
            checkVerifiedUser: function() {
                return userVerifiedCheck();
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Try it, and you'll see. Of course it's possible. Why wouldn't it? $state.go() doesn't have any idea if it called by a service, a controller, a directive or anythig else. And it doesn't care.

Comment: @JBNizet ohk ! i tried ! but it does not work !

Comment: Then show what you tried, explain what you expect it to do and what it does instead, so that we can tell you what's wrong in your code.

Comment: @JBNizet Edited ! please check the code

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. `resolve` members are supposed to be functions returning data that will then be injected in the state controller. Moreover, you can't use services in the configuration phase. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet I am trying to protect the view ! using resolve ! If the user is not verified he shud get redirected to another state !

Comment: _How_ does it not work?

Comment: I don't think that is a good way to do that. You should probably listen to the $stateChangeStart event and call preventDefault() to avoid loading the state if the user is not verified. See http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state and search for $stateChangeStart

Comment: @JBNizet i read it on many blogs that resolve is a good way to  protect views ! I am using it for my hybrid mobile app and i have many views to protect according to conditions ! so will it not be too much load for every state change if i put it in $stateChangeStart ?